# Why my home folder has little space even though the disk mounted has plenty of it?

Tags: mount, 20.04

I have installed ubuntu 20.04 on an 120GB SSD then I mounted my home folder on a larger disk as `/etc/fstab` says the (`/home/pc_magas` is my home folder):

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=7bbdd0c0-a528-4144-b05e-10319a15be39 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=419d21fa-f1e1-4bca-bbc7-fa71eb3882a1 /mnt        ext4    defaults        0       0
/home/pc_magas                /mnt/pc_magas   none    bind
/mnt/var                  /var        none    bind
```

The disks I have are (as `sudo dlkid` says):

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="7bbdd0c0-a528-4144-b05e-10319a15be39" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="50b1776c-781e-4a90-af3e-f1af03c714d8"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="419d21fa-f1e1-4bca-bbc7-fa71eb3882a1" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="000332e6-01"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sdg1: UUID="B5F4-61B7" TYPE="vfat"
```

The hard disk is the `/dev/sdb1` having this size:

```
$ df -h /dev/sdb1
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1       458G  3,1G  432G   1% /mnt
```

And the home folder has this size:

```
$ df -h /home/pc_magas/
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       110G  103G  1,9G  99% /
```

So why the mounted home folder has little space even though it is mounted on a different disk?

Also why `/home/pc_magas` is mounted on `/dev/sda1` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumming that `/dev/sda1` is the smallest disk and runs out of space ,you mismounted the `/home/pc_magas`as you mentioned on `/etc/fstab`. Also I assume that the OS is installed on `/dev/sda1`

```
/home/pc_magas                /mnt/pc_magas   none    bind
```

To solve this boot from a live usb. Then mount your disks:

```
mkdir /mnt/sda1
mkdir /mnt/sdb1
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdb1
```

Copy the files from `/mnt/sda1` into `/mnt/sdb1`

```
sudo rsync -ravp /mnt/sda1/home/pc_magas /mnt/sdb1/pc_magas
```

Notice the `-p` option that preserves any file ownership and permissions

And then fix the `/etc/fstab` by:

1. `sudo nano /mnt/sda1/etc/fstab`
2. Set:

   `/mnt/pc_magas   /home/pc_magas none    bind 0 0`

   Instead of:

   `/home/pc_magas                /mnt/pc_magas   none    bind`
3. Save and exit

Then the only thing to do it to empty out the `/dev/sda1/home/pc_magas`, keep in mind this is also important because once booted into a normal OS, you will still have lack of space and you cannot release space in `/dev/sda1`. The command to do that is:

```
rm -rf /mnt/sda1/home/pc_magas/*
```

Then boot normally to your host OS anbd enjoy the ubuntu 20.04